# Multicast with select

Tags: python, sockets, select, multicast, python-sockets

My server work fine with my select function :

```
readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, timeout)
```

Here is the code for writable loop :

```
for s in writable:
    try:
        next_msg = message_queues[s].get_nowait()
    except Queue.Empty:
        # No messages waiting so stop checking for writability.
        print >>sys.stderr, 'output queue for', s.getpeername(), 'is empty'
        outputs.remove(s)
    else:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s" to %s' % (next_msg, s.getpeername())
        s.send(next_msg)
```

s is the socket object. Here the code send only to the client who is sending something.
I just want to multicast the next_msg to each other writables sockets so i tried that :

```
for s in writable:
    try:
        next_msg = message_queues[s].get_nowait()
    except Queue.Empty:
        # No messages waiting so stop checking for writability.
        print >>sys.stderr, 'output queue for', s.getpeername(), 'is empty'
        outputs.remove(s)
    else:
        for multicast in writable:
            print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s" to %s' % (next_msg, multicast.getpeername())
            multicast.send(next_msg)
```

But that don't work, it send always only to the sender.

Comment: what do you mean your server works fine with the select function? have you tested that the output arrays are correct? It looks like your problem is in there. Can you please include the code for that function unless you are 100% sure it's working?

Comment: @Sheena Hello, thank you for your help. I mean that i've a server that working with multi client without blocking and without thread because i use the select function. But, the server only send packets to the client who was sending the packet. I'm trying to modify it to have a multicast server like a chat : every client receive the packets of others. But when i wrote a for statement to do the multicast it doesn't work as multicast : the server only send to the client senders : like a miror, like i wrote anything... i don't know how to debug this... i think i'll try to make a global queue

Answer (score 0):

Ok multicast is ok now.
I thought that writable contained a list of writable socket but it's only one selected. I don't really understand the first loop with "for s in writable" if there is only one socket in writable but...
So ! it works with inputs list :

```
for multicast in inputs:
        if multicast is not server:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'sending "%s" to %s' % (next_msg, multicast.getpeername())
                multicast.send(next_msg)
```